# Python Fill empty cells with average for row's group

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I basically have a csv file with two columns: PLACE (string) and quantity (int). Some of my quantity rows are empty and I want to fill them with the AVERAGE for the group of PLACE.

For example:

PLACE, QUANTITY

AUSTRALIA, 4

AUSTRALIA, 2

USA, 3

AUSTRALIA,

you can see that one 'AUSTRALIA' has no associated qty. I want that row of 'AUS' to have the average of all the 'AUS' rows that do have a value. How would I do this in python? Ive tried this below, but it doesnt do anything. Maybe because I filled the NAs with NaN its not filling?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
# READ THE DATA FILES
csv_file = open('MY_CSV.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)


# fill all NAs and replace with the average of that PLACE
AverageReplace = df.groupby('PLACE')['QUANTITY'].mean()
df['QUANTITY'].fillna(AverageReplace, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y=a.fillna(0).groupby('PLACE').agg('mean')['Quantity']

a['Quantity'] = a[['PLACE','Quantity']].apply(lambda x: y[x['PLACE']] if np.isnan(x['Quantity']) else x['Quantity'],axis=1)
```

Try this. it works on my system

Comment: Yeh thats it thx. But how does this work exactly? i just dont get the lambda (second line) and last bit where you have "else x['quantity'], axis =1"

Comment: lambda functions are inline functions. What's happening is it takes each row consisting of the two columns and checks if the qty in that row is null. if it's null, it replaces the null value by the mean value calculated for the place in that row. If you print everything you may understand better

Answer (score 0):

below is another way of doing that.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Place':['Australia', 'Australia', 'USA', 'Australia'], 'Quantity':[4,2,3,np.nan] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].fillna(df[df['Place']=='Australia']['Quantity'].mean())
```